# Simply showing a component Only if another component is showing - Ext JS

Tags: function, extjs, hide, panel, show

So I have a hidden container item:

```
id: 'category_search', hidden: true, ...
```

And another hidden panel:

```
{ xtype: 'panel', id: 'mylist', hidden: true ...
```

Here i have a controller to show `category search` **ONLY** when `mylist` is Not hidden - handled by the click of a button `categorized_search`:

```
catSearch: function() {
    var grid = Ext.getCmp('mylist');
    if(grid.isHidden){ //checking to see if the component is hidden
        console.log('Please enter a search');
    }
    else
    {       
        Ext.getCmp('category_search').show(); //Shows category search
    }
}
```

When I click my categorized_search button, it does *not* display when mylist *is* showing, and *will* display when mylist is *not* showing. How can I fix this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AbstractComponent.isHidden()` and `AbstractComponent.isVisible()` are functions, not properties.  Add parentheses to your `if` statement.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-isHidden

Comment: Once again, you have saved lives. Now enjoy your karma.